# I cannot import firebase version 9 in my express.js files

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, npm

I want to import my firebase variables in my file:

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
  const firebase = require('../firebase');
 const firestore=firebase.firestore();

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

Here is my firebase initialization code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require('dotenv').config();
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL:process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    projectId:process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET ,
    storageBucket:process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID ,
    appId:process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID 
  };

 const result=firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 module.exports=result;
```

Whenever I import my result variable

```
  const firebase = require('../firebase');
```

I got error

```
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Trekxplorer\backend\firebase.js:1:18)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```